# Images patch relative to [custom] view directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

In my Rails application, user may have custom page templates (not for the application) which are stored in `public/user_templates/user1/`

the view .erb file is also stored there in the user template folder. There is an images folder inside every template folder. How can I use the relative paths of the images in the .erb file?

For example `<img src"images/image1" />`

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access static files inside of your app directory without passing them through a route somehow.  You should create a directory for each user_id in the public/images folder of your application, then store the images for each user there.  Then you can access those images at `<img src="images/#{user_id}/image1.jpg" />` or with a view helper `image_tag "#{user_id}/image1.jpg"` Depending on your application, you may want to use [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. We are already using the same thing -- with a slight variation though i.e. referencing the same user folder through user_id where the .erb file and images folder is stored.

Comment: Then I suppose you'll have to create an image-serving controller and corresponding route to serve those files, OR a piece of Rack middleware to catch those image requests and serve the static files, the latter is probably a performance boost over the former.

Comment: hmm... Could you please show me an example, as I haven't worked much with Rack?

Comment: I can recommend starting with Ryan Bate's ever-helpful screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware